# Animated characters on an overlay of camera capture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, camera, core-animation, overlay

I was wondering how the [characters in this app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnWWEA7an0I) are animated on screen. Is it possible to have a video with transparent background to put as the overlay of camera capture ? Is this just a set of UIImages animated together ? These characters seems more animated than simple gifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely an OpenGL animation you are seeing overlaid on the camera display. See one of the [often cited answers of Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473894/alternatives-to-creating-an-opengl-texture-from-a-captured-video-frame-to-overla) on how to do that - includes a linked example project (that dude rocks).

To achieve that effect, you use the input of the camera, put that on a planar object as a texture and render your stuff (highly animated characters or even naked, dancing robot women) on top of it, presto.